# 1.875" bicycle rim width

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, wheels, rims

Last year I bought a used wheel set on marketplace from a guy that rides off-road/trail.
He said they were strong and since I intended to put an electric motor w/assist on the bike I figured it couldn't hurt to have a stronger wheel on front.
They are for 26" tires, according to him at the time, and they were/are very light and clean, but they measure 1 and 7/8 inches wide, compared to a regular wheel that measures (approx) 1.5 inches wide.
They are made by "Panther" but I can't find anything relative to them on the 'net, and I can no longer find his contact information.

Can anyone tell me what these wheels were intended for?
Will they take a wider tire than a "normal" rim takes (I was hoping also to put a 26x2.5 tire on them)?
I'd like to read/learn more about these rims.
If anyone can "catch me up", or direct me to where I can learn more I would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "normal" wheel. There are different rim widths for different purposes. These are probably older mountain-bike wheels.

Regarding tire compatibility: a given rim width will be compatible with a range of tire widths. Different manufacturers may have slightly different recommended ranges, but [this](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#width) and [this](https://www.wtb.com/pages/tire-rim-fit-chart) are good starting points. Note that this is using the width across the *inside* of the rim, not outside. My guess is that you'll be OK with 2.5" tires, but I'd measure to be sure.